# Error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to create a simple app without activity that just open a webpage in the browser.
This is my code:

```
package com.example.johnny.myapplication3;


import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

/**
 * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing Fundamentals</a>
 */
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

But I get this error: Error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)
Why ?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and rebuilding? That fixed it for me.

Comment: what do you mean for cleaning ?

Comment: I don't know which IDE you are using, but for visual studio check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx

Comment: you should call `context.startActivity(browserIntent);`

Comment: Yeesh, lots of irrelevant comments here. No one seems to react to the fact that the OP is trying to create an app, but is actually creating a test case. If the app has no entry point it cannot be started. Cleaning the IDE does not change the fact that the class in question doesn't have the method he's trying to call. Calling context.startActivity wouldn't help either; ApplicationTestCase does have a member mContext, but you are still lacking a way to get your application started - most likely the OP does not want to create an ApplicationTestCase at all.

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationTestCase does not have a method startActivity. If you're creating an app, not a test case, it does not make sense to use TestCase classes at all.

Without some more info on what you want to do it's hard to help more.

"a simple app without activity that just open a webpage in the browser"

How is your app supposed to be started? If it doesn't have any activity it will not have any launcher icon. Is it supposed to start by reacting to a broadcast intent or something like that? If so, you need a receiver to handle that intent and perform the actions you need to perform. You cannot just create an app with no entry point at all, how is the system supposed to know when and how to launch it?

Assuming you do want an icon in the launcher, then you do need to register an activity. That activity could in turn finish itself and launch the browser using startActivity, but the activity must be there to act as an entry point.